# Relation between difference of values of an increasing function and difference of its arguments

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

$$a_n=max_{\{\forall x, x':|f (x)-f (x')|\leq\frac {1}{n}\}}|x-x'|$$
So $a_n $ is the maximal distance between points $x$ and $x'$ such that $|f (x)-f (x')|\leq\frac {1}{n}$ for a strictly increasing continuous $f$. $a_n$ is decreasing and has (as i suppose) limit $0$ as $n\to\infty$, so it seems that there should be some function $w$ such that
$$|x-x'|\leq w(|f (x)-f (x')|)$$
What is this $w$?

Comment: Is your w a constant or a function? There need not be any positive constant w satisfying your inequality.

Comment: You can define $w(t)$ as $\sup \{|x-x'|:|f(x)-f(x')| \leq t\}$. The assertion that $a_n \to 0$ traanslates into continuity of $w$ at 0.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes, $w$ should be a function here.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thats something like minimal modulus of continuity, not very useful.